# Embed a UIView animation in a func that needs to return once the animation is completed

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

This sounded simple, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Context: a VC tells a view to animate itself and the VC waits the animation to be completed before.

I thought about doing something like this:

In ViewController:

```
loadingView.animate()
```

In LoadingView (UIView subclass):

```
animate() -> Bool {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.imageViewCenterYConstraint.constant -= 20
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion {
         return true // This line obviously doesn't work.
    })
}
```

I do not want to include the rest of the code inside the completion block. The rest of the code is in the VC.

I suspect that all this should rather be done with an additional completion handler to add to the animate func.

PS: Just in case you know of a better solution/best practices, here is more context: I display a loading animation and remove it once I have retrieved data from the network. I always want to wait for the animation to complete before removing, even if the network data was already downloaded. Don't want to stop the animation at half of it.

Comment: An additional completion block or a delegate is a way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return from a function once an async task is complete. (Ok, it might be possible, but it is a **VERY BAD IDEA**. You'd have to block the main thread waiting for the async function to complete, which would freeze your UI and cause the system springboard process to terminate your app if it takes too long.)

You need to write your function to take a completion block and invoke it once the animation is complete. Something like this:

```
animate( completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.imageViewCenterYConstraint.constant -= 20
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion {
        completion(true)
    })
}
```

(I think that's right but I still do not have closure syntax perfect so it might need adjustment.)

Answer (score 1):

For your problem use escaping closures to return it once animation is done.
Write function for the same and then your code will look like this.

```
func animate( completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {

        //Do your animation stuff here
        //self.imageViewCenterYConstraint.constant -= 20
        //self.layoutIfNeeded()

     }, completion: {(true) in

         completion(true)

     })

}
```

You can call this method like this

```
animate { (isDone) in

     // Animation is completed do your own stuff here


}
```